# Multiple average aggregations in elasticsearch Java API

Tags: java, elasticsearch

Is there a Java code equivalent to this sub aggregation.
I need Java code to build the sub aggregation object.

```
{
  "query": {
    "SOME BOOL QUERIES HERE"
  },
 "aggs" : {
        "trs_timestamp" : {
            "date_histogram" : {
                "field" : "trs_timestamp",
                "interval" : "day"
            },
        "aggs" : {
                "AvgTT" : { "avg" : { "field" : "action_time" }},
                "AvgST" : { "avg" : { "field" : "st" }},
                "AvgCALC" : { "avg" : { "field" : "ncalc" }},
                "AvgRC" : { "avg" : { "field" : "rc" }},
                "AvgFR" : { "avg" : { "field" : "st" }}
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Elasticsearch Java API and `AggregationBuilders` for this, e.g.:

```
SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch()
        .addAggregation(AggregationBuilders.avg("AvgTT").field("action_time"))
        .addAggregation(AggregationBuilders.avg("AvgST").field("st"))
        .addAggregation(AggregationBuilders.avg("AvgCALC").field("ncalc"))
        .addAggregation(AggregationBuilders.avg("AvgRC").field("rc"))
        .addAggregation(AggregationBuilders.avg("AvgFR").field("st"))
        .execute()
        .actionGet();
```

Answer (score 0):

By example:

```
SearchResponse sr = node.client().prepareSearch()
        .setQuery( /* your query */ )
        .addAggregation( /* add an aggregation */ )
        .execute().actionGet();
```

You can see that there is `addAggregation` not `set` implying that you can add multiple aggregations to a query.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-aggs.html